# HttpResponseMessageの応答が全くない…

Tags: c#, wpf, azure

タイトルの通りなのですが、条件があります。

- ConsoleアプリのProgram.csで実行すると問題なく、レスポンスを得る事ができる。
- WPFプロジェクトのソースコード上ではレスポンスが帰って来ない。(MainWindow.xaml.cs)

レスポンスが帰ってこないコードは以下の内容です。　AzureMLのAPIの結果を取得する内容です。

```
public class Study
{
    public Study()
    {
        InvokeRequestResponseService().Wait();
    }

    public class StringTable
    {
        public string[] ColumnNames { get; set; }
        public string[,] Values { get; set; }
    }

    static async Task InvokeRequestResponseService()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var scoreRequest = new
            {

                Inputs = new Dictionary<string, StringTable>() {
                    {
                        "input1",
                        new StringTable()
                        {
                            ColumnNames = new string[] {"メーカー", "燃料タイプ", "ドアの数", "車体形状", "エンジンの場所", "エンジンサイズ", "値段"},
                            Values = new string[,] {  { "audi", "gas", "two", "sedan", "front", "136", "0" }  }
                        }
                    },
                },
                GlobalParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                }
            };
            const string apiKey = "***myKey***"; // Replace this with the API key for the web service
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("***myUri***");


            //↓ここのレスポンスがなく、これ以上進まない…
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The request failed with status code: {0}", response.StatusCode));

                // Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp, which are useful for debugging the failure
                Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());

                string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ブレイクポイントで張って待っていても何もレスポンスがないため、アプリはフリーズ状態です。
何か原因がわかる方、ご教授いただきたいです。
よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: ちなみにFormアプリでも同じです。HttpResponseMessageの返信がありません。。

Comment: さらに追記ですがFormアプリのProgram.cs内で、上記コードを貼り付けて実行するとHttpResponseMessageのレスポンスを得ることができました。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の2種類の処理がデッドロックしています。

1. `InvokeRequestResponseService().Wait()`
2. `InvokeRequestResponseService()`内の`await`

WPFアプリで実行される`await`は標準では後続の処理をUIスレッドで実行しようとします。しかしUIスレッドでは`Task.Wait()`をずっと実行しているため、`await`が完了しないのです。

対策としてはまず`Task`を`await`する前に`.ConfigureAwait(false)`を実行し後続の処理のスレッドを変更する方法があります。例えば以下のようなコーディングになります。

```
 await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest).ConfigureAwait(false)
```

より重要な点としてはUIスレッドで`Task.Wait()`を実行すべきではないということです。折角非同期処理を行っているのにUIをブロックしてはあまり意味がありません。ですので`InvokeRequestResponseService().Wait()`を例えば以下のように変更すると画面がフリーズすることはなくなります。

```
IsEnabled = false; // 画面をロード中表示に変更する
// awaitで待機
await InvokeRequestResponseService();
IsEnabled = true;
```

どちらか一方でも効果はありますが、両方行った方が良いです。

Comment: HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest); の部分をHttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);とする認識であっていますでしょうか。。

Comment: またIsEnalbed = false; await InvokeResuestResponseService(); IsEnabled = trueにする場所は上記のコードでいうStudy()コンストラクタ内であっていますでしょうか。。

Comment: @KazukiSaito `ConfigureAwait(false)`についてはその通りですが、後者はコンストラクターの中で`IsEnabled`に類するビューの設定を操作したり、あるいはビューモデルのプロパティを変更したりするのは設計上無理があります。コンストラクターでいきなり非同期処理を開始するのではなく、ビューモデルやコントロールのイベントハンドラー内で状態を管理するようにしてください。